# ALM 11.0 REST-API - copying entire folder

Tags: rest, alm

I want to copy the entire test-folder with all subfolders and tests from one place to another in ALM Test Plan. Is there a way to do it at all in ALM 11.0?

Moving the folder seems to be easy - sending a PUT request http://HOST//qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN/projects/PROJECT/test-folder/TEST-FOLDER-ID with body:

```
<Entity Type="test">
<Fields>
<Field Name="parent-id">
<Value>10000</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Entity>
```

I wonder what to do to copy automatically... I create the tests themselves and then change the parent id for them, but ALM 11.0 does not support design steps and I have no idea how to copy a test case so that it retains the design steps. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better to use ALM 12.20 or later version. ALM REST API was officially released after ALM 12.20. Some functions was not well designed and developed before the official release version.

Comment: If I could, I would, but it's not my decision to use this given version of ALM...